# click a button inside html table and get the value on the same row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm having a problem with clicking a button inside html table and get the value on the same row and pass it to an input FullName
. how can i do that? thanks

```
<td><?php echo $r['signatoryname'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $r['signatoryposition'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $r['signatoryoffice'] ?></td>
                                <td>

                                <button type="button" class="btnedit btn btn-xs btn-success">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>Edit
                                </button>
                                </td>

<input id="Fullname" class="form-control" >
```

Comment: where is your javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
$(".btnedit").click(function () {
    var name = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
    $("#Fullname").val(name);
});
```

`Closest("tr")` will return the clicked button's parent tr.

Then you can find the child td using its index.

`find("td:eq(0)")` will return the first `td` of selected `tr`. In your case, it will return **signatoryname**.

Likewise, you can use `find("td:eq(1)")` & `find("td:eq(2)")`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, or change your structure as per you hierarchy .

```
$('.btnedit').click(
 function(){
  var uName = $(this).parent().prev().html();
  $(this).parent().next().children('.form-control').val(uName)
 });
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nt3s3z50/)

Comment: as per your requirement you a have a table where you have multiple rows , so in this case please avoid using id selector .

as we know id should be unique.